# What is the BigO complexity of intersection for TreeSet algorithm?

Tags: java, complexity-theory

What is the BigO complexity of following lgorithms:

```
boolean intersection(TreeSet<?> set1, TreeSet<?> set1){
   if(set1.size() > set2.size()){
      return intersection(set2, set1);
   }
   for (Object e: set1){
       if(set2.contains(e)) return true;
   }
   return false;

}
```

UPDATE:

```
 N:=set1.size()
  K:=set2.size()
```

The possible answers:
 **O(N*K) or O(N*log(K)) or O(K*log(N)) or O(N+K)**

Comment: Are those tree sets sorted and balanced?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak TreeSet are sorted

Comment: what is your guess?  we aren't getting the homework grade...

Comment: It should be `O(n * log k)`, you could do in `O(n)` if you use a "two pointer" approach. Maybe you want to look up the intersection of two sorted sets.

Comment: If you do a merge sort/intersection instead it will be `O(N+K)`

Comment: This question belongs on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
O(N * log M)
```

N - size of set1, M - size of set2

Because we iterating on set1 elements (`N`)
and for each iteration we call `contains` method which is `logM` complexity

[TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) javadoc:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic
>   operations (add, remove and contains).

Comment: i think the performance is not `O(N log K)`

Comment: @Sage I would not agree that tree iteration is `O(n * log n)`. All that iterator does it's inorder traversal. That's definitely O(n).

Comment: Well, how are we supposed to do in-order traversal on a tree?  What kind of relation among the node must exist ? is there any supporting evidence or implementation that tells that we can actually traverse all of the element of a balanced-binary search tree in `O(n)` ?

Comment: There is parent for each node. So we actually move up in the tree. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471731/in-order-successor-in-binary-search-tree

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe that i have overlooked this premature theoretical knowledge. Actually the `successor(e)` call made me confused in the `next()` call as i have pointed out in my answer :(.